# How can a role user see only own products not other users in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, permissions, user-roles, role

I am troubling with user roles in Magento 2. When I am trying to assign product permission to a user who can see only own products but all products displaying to him. How can I set a role in which user can see only own products and create reports of own product? Is it possible?

Comment: r u looking for multi-vendor ?

Comment: by default magento user permissions are an acl for access to certain areas of the admin panel it is not for admin specific products

Comment: Please check https://amasty.com/advanced-permissions-for-magento-2.html . I think you are looking for something like this.

Comment: @ lalit mohan yes i am looking for multi-vendor